# Failover clustering or Network Load Balance on windows server

Tags: windows, networking, sql-server, cluster, failover

I have 2 servers with Windows 2008 R2 standard OS.

I need to create a cluster in case on of the servers goes down ; so the other one will continue provide services.

The services we mostly use are a SQL Server and server side Software for cameras.

Does the Network Load Balancer will help me with that or I must uppgrade to enterprise edition in order to use failover clustering?

Answer (score 3):

Network Load Balancing will *not* work in your case. It's not meant to provide failover capabilities (as in the name, it balances load across servers for various things). SQL Server has failover clustering capabilities and is easy to set up, but you will need Enterprise for this.

Comment: to make this more clear: You need Windows Server Enterprise for cluster but on SQL (starting with 2005) standard is enough for a two node cluster.